# Button, Panel and ListBox moving on the form during runtime

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm newbie in visual c# programming, I'm making this application and I've got this problem.
I've created a form based application, in form1 I've got some controls like Button, ListBox, Radio etc. grouped into 4 panel.In the design view I've created the GUI of my form and set all the proprieties of my control. When I run the program the control has moved or resized.
They are not in the position where I've placed them before.
I can't understand why!
Please help me

Thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following properties in your panels 
`Dock, Anchor`